# $\mid G:H\mid$=2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite group and $H \leq G$ such that $\mid G:H \mid =2$, then $H$ contains all of elements of $G$ of odd order.

there is a hint: $x^{2k-1}=1$ implies $x=(x^{2})^{k}$.

The first thing I would think about it is, since $\mid G:H \mid =2$, that implies that $H$ is normal in $G$. Hence, $G/H$ is a quotient group.

would someone please help me out with that. You do not have to use the hint if you have a different way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets show that $H$ is a normal subgroup. Let $h\in G$. If $h\in H$ then $hHh^{-1}=H$. If $h\not\in H$ then, $hHh^{-1} \cap hH = \phi$. Thus, $hHh^{-1}\subset H$. Now look at  the group $G/H$.
Let $x$ be an element of $G$ which is not in $H$. Elements of $G/H$ are $H$ and $Hx$. And its a group. So $Hx .Hx = H $ and hence $Hx^2=H$.So, $x^2 \in$ $H$   $\forall$  x   $\in G$.
Now $x^{2k-1} = e \implies x=x^{2k}=(x^{k})^2 \in H. $

Answer (score 0):

Try the contrapositive, showing that every element in $G \setminus H$ has even order. You've already discovered that $G/H$ is a cyclic group of order 2. So every element $x \in G \setminus H$ gets sent to the nontrivial element $\bar x \in G/H$ under the projection map $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$. But if $x$ has order $m$, then
$$1_{G/H} = \pi(1_G) = \pi(x^m) =  \bar x^m$$
So $\bar x$ has order dividing $m$. But we know $\bar x$ has order 2 by the structure of $G/H$, so 2 divides $m$ and therefore $m$ is even.